# PowerShell Invoke-Sqlcmd - Does not return DataTable or DataSet

Tags: .net, dataset, powershell-2.0, boxing, unboxing

If I do the following,

```
PS > $a = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance <blah> -Database <blah> -Query "SELECT <blah>"
```

(where  is just a placeholder for valid stuff)

Then the type returned looks like this:

```
PS > $a.gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                         BaseType        
-------- -------- ----                         --------        
True     True     Object[]                     System.Array
```

Ideally I would like to pass $a to a function that accepts a .NET type of the form System.Data.DataSet (or similar).

For detail I am using Chad Miller's SQLPS module which wraps the official MS distributions for earlier SQL server (SQL Server 2008) on PowerShell 2 under Windows 7.

I suspect this may have something to do with boxing and unboxing, but it's not clear to me.

Is there a way of returning the query result as a System.Data.DataSet type?

Answer (score 3):

As of the July 2016 version of sqlps, you can simply do this:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd "select 1 as foo" -OutputAs DataTables
```

Good stuff!

Answer (score 1):

This is a way for return a [dataset] type not using `invoke-sqlcmd` ( can't  find a way...)

```
$sql="SELECT <blah> FROM <dbo.blah>"
$connectionstring= "Server='myblahserver';database='blah';trusted_connection=yes;" 
$ds = new-object data.dataset 
$da = New-Object system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter $sql, $connectionstring 
$null = $da.Fill($ds) 
$ds.ExtendedProperties["sql"]= $sql 
$ds.ExtendedProperties["connectionstring"]= $connectionstring 
$ds
```

Comment: Thanks - I'm aware of that - but am looking for a more "PowerShell" friendly manner.  If there isn't one then I will just have to use PowerShell as a wrapper for calling .NET -- but it does seem rather unedifying.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I have found to do it is to create a function for converting an array into a data table using the code provided here:

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/4208a159-a52e-4b99-83d4-8048468d29dd

Once you have this function loaded, then you can take the results of invoke-sqlcmd and pipe it into the function as so:

```
$results = Invoke-Sqlcmd -inputfile $scriptpath -ServerInstance $instance
$dt = $results | Out-Datatable
```